# What's the exact distinction read() and readline()?

Tags: python

I suppose `read()` does read a file as a string,  while `readline()` reads a file line by line. There's a **size** positional argument for the two method which default to -1 (read everything).  Now my problem begins, isn't `x.read() == x. readlines()` since both defaults to -1 which reads everything?

Here's my code:

```
with open('some_file.png') as my_file:
    check = my_file.read()
     print(b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n' in check) #all PNG files has the byte string. #This returned True
   check = my_file.readlines()
    print(b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n' in check) #this one returned False
```

I thought both should return True since I read everything without sizing.  A good explanation would help. Thanks

Comment: `.readline` is not the same thing as `.readlines`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` returns a string with a full content of the file.
`readlines()` returns a list of the content of the file.

Let's take a look at an example:

`test_list = ['abc', 'png start', 'temp']`

`test_str = ['abc png start temp']`

And if you will test if `png` is in list you will get `False`, because it will try to find such element as a whole in elements of the list. If you will try to check if `png start` is in list you will get `True`. But for `test_str` in both cases you will get `True`.

Answer (score 3):

`read()` returns a string with the contents of the file

`readlines()` returns a list of all the lines in the file

More:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readlines.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp